# Insert Text Leftwards in Overwrite Mode

Tags: text-editing, insert, right-to-left

How can I insert text so that the cursor stays in the same position while text I type is shifted to the left, overwriting existing text? For example:

```
   row_title: some words
   old_title: letters here
            ^

   row_title: some words
 newer_title: letters here
            ^
```

Where the `^` represents the position of the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no predefined way to do this.

You'll probably want to start by defining your own replacement for `overwrite-mode`, mirroring what is done for `overwrite-mode` but:

- Switching (for example), the keys for commands `delete-backward-char` and `delete-forward-char`.
- Binding your own replacement command for `quoted-insert` (`C-q`), using `backward-delete-char` in place of `delete-char` in the definition.

However, because there are multiple predefined Lisp functions that use `overwrite-mode` (e.g., check the value and do something accordingly), you might just want to advise `overwrite-mode`, instead of defining a replacement command.

Finally, I would ask why you want to do this?  What is your actual use case?

---

**Update after your use-case comment:**

In that case:

- Try **`M-x picture-mode`** -- see the Emacs manual, node [*Picture-Mode*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Picture-Mode.html) and its 4 subnodes.
- Maybe try the `table` package -- see the Emacs manual, node [*Text Based Tables*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html) and its 8 subnodes.

Comment: My use case is editing ascii tables while keeping things in line.

Comment: @Ell Even `align-regexp` might help you out in that case. Do you want to update the question with a sample of ascii table text you need to edit?